# In maven Project testng.xml runs successfully but pom.xml is giving Compilation error

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng

I have been trying to resolve the issue but couldn't figure it out. Would you like to share your thoughts on this?
I did add maven-surefire-plugin plugins but it didn't work and because of pom.xml my jenkins built is also failing.

sharing my pom.xml and testng.xml below.

1. testng.xml

```
 *<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
      <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.pages.VisibilityAnnotationDemo"/>
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Test -->
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->*
```

2)Pom.xml

```
    *<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>VRsessions</groupId>
    <artifactId>VRsessions</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>VRsessions</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>

        <testSourceDirectory>src/main/java/com/pages/VisibilityAnnotationDemo</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <includes>
                        <include>VisibilityAnnotationDemo.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        


    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Error log as below

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project VRsessions: Compilation failure: Compilation failure. 
package org.testng does not exist
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Test
[ERROR] location: class com.pages.VisibilityAnnotationDemo
```

Comment: Please add the compile error info. Probably that gives more info that only this code snippets. Also try to fix you post's layout issues to make more clear what's really inside your snippets.

Comment: Did you do `Maven-> Update project` after adding testng dependency?

Comment: @GauthamM yes, I did that.

Comment: @Tejas is the test source directory `<testSourceDirectory>src/main/java/com/pages/VisibilityAnnotationDemo</testSourceDirectory>` correct? Shouldn't it be `test` instead of `main`?  `src/test/java..............`

Comment: @GauthamM...I always create java class in src/main. should it be in src/test folder?

Comment: @Tejas usually the project related classes come under src/main and test classes come under src/test

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem please change the dependency scope from test to compile:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.14.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

To

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**1) compile** This is the **default scope**, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

> **Note: By default the scope is compile**

**2) test** This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.

> **Note: test scope allows to use dependencies only for the test phase.**

**Screenshot With `<scope>test</scope>`**

[image]